# Mistake when using Lagrange's theorem group theory.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, self-learning, proof-explanation

Recently, I learned that a conclusion of Lagrange's theorem is the following :

if $G$ is a finite group let $a \in G$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ if $a^n=e$ then $O(a)|n$

I might be missing out something but I don't understand how this theorem works.

For example let take $G=\mathbb{Z^∗_7}$, G cyclic since $7$ is a prime number.

and also $|G|=p-1=7-1=6$ lets take $2\in G$ we know that $2^6=e=1$, but for $n=11$ we get that $2^{11}=e$ but $6 \not| 11$ when $6=O(2)$.

Could somebody help me understand what I missing out, I can't figrue it out.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I don't know how I didn't notice that.
Thank everybody!

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_7$ contains $7$ elements, not $6$.

Comment: But $2^{11} = 4$...

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$, the *units* as a multiplicative group, contains $6$ elements.

Comment: @abcdef I think he is talking about $U(7)$ which has 6 elements

Comment: Sorry for confusion I'm talking about $Z^*_7$ is a $+$ group meaning when $2^6=2*2*2*2*2*2=1$

Comment: @JaVaPG Why do you think that $2^{11}=e=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{7}$? Actually $2^{11}=2048$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ so $2^{11} =4\mbox{ mod }7$ which is not $1$. Are you perhaps confusing multiplication with addition as a group operation in $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$?

Comment: $G$ is not cyclic !

Comment: @HirenGarai G is cyclic. In fact, every prime power possesses a primitive root. As 7 is a prime, it does have a primitive root/ generator. In fact, G = <5>

Comment: Yes ! My mistake ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly stated that if $a^n=e$ in a finite group $G$, then $\operatorname{ord}(a)\mid n$. For $a=2$ and $G=U(7)$ the first computation is correct, because $2^3=1$ in $G$ and $3\mid 6$. The second computation, however, is wrong, because $2^{11}=4$, and not $1$. Hence it is not surprising that the conclusion $3\mid 11$ is wrong, too.
In fact, $2^{11}=2048\equiv 4\bmod 7$. Also note that $\operatorname{ord}(2)=3$, and not $6$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $\{ e,a,a^2,a^3,\dots, a^{n-1}\}$
forms a subgroup as you can verify. What is its order? What does Lagrange's theorem tell you about the order of the group?

Comment: This does nothing to address the specific confusion of the OP

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft the confusion would seem to be cleared up in the comment as it was a computational error. Also does nothing is a bit strong, no?

Comment: I talking about a multiplication group while $G={1,2,3,4,5,6}$.